# No entiendo por qué Lorem Ipsum se transforma en El Quijote

Tags: c++

He encontrado este código navegando en páginas de ejemplos de C++:

```cpp
#include "lorem_ipsum"

#include <iostream>

INCIDIDUNT main() { EXCEPTEUR<VENIAM>(LABORUM); }
```

Que produce la siguiente salida:

```
En un lugar de La Mancha de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme no hace mucho tiempo atras que un hidalgo cabalgaba de los de lanza en ristre rocin flaco y galgo corredor
```

No conozco la palabra clave `INCIDIDUNT`, pero sospecho que debe ser un alias de `int`, también parece que `EXCEPTEUR` es una función plantilla que recibe `LABORUM` como parámetro, aunque no veo dónde está definido. Sin más información no se si `VENIAM` es un tipo o un valor.

Lo que sí que se es que todas esas palabras me son familiares, forman parte del "[*Lorem Ipsum*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum)":

> *Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.*

Algo más que obvio al ver la primera inclusión del programa:

```cpp
#include "lorem_ipsum"
```

Que llama la atención que no tenga extensión. El contenido de ese archivo es casi incomprensible:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

#define ALIQUIP auto
#define IRURE ALIQUIP
#define EXERCITATION template
#define SUNT(AMET) signed AMET
#define ALIQUA(VELIT) unsigned VELIT
#define CILLIUM char
#define MAGNA long
#define CONSEQUAT MAGNA
#define DOLORE double
#define OFFICIA float
#define INCIDIDUNT int
#define OCCAECAT(X) std::cout << X
#define ID_EST_LABORUM(REPREHENDERIT, CUPIDATAT) CILLIUM CUPIDATAT[] = #REPREHENDERIT;
#define CULPA using
#define DESERUNT decltype
#define QUIS void
#define COMMODO return
#define NULLA typeid

ALIQUIP LUPTATE(IRURE CONSECTETUR) { COMMODO NULLA(CONSECTETUR).name(); }
ID_EST_LABORUM(Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing Elit sed do 
eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore Magna aliqua zut enim ad 
minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex 
ea commodo consequat Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur Excepteur sint occaecat 
cupidatat non proident sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id 
est laborum, PARIATUR); CULPA  CONSECTETUR  =  std::tuple<SUNT( CILLIUM ), CILLIUM,
MAGNA   DOLORE,   DOLORE, OFFICIA, ALIQUA( CILLIUM ), SUNT( INCIDIDUNT ), ALIQUA(),
MAGNA, ALIQUA(MAGNA), SUNT(MAGNA CONSEQUAT), ALIQUA(CONSEQUAT MAGNA)>; EXERCITATION
<ALIQUIP EUISMOD> IRURE PROIDENT( ALIQUA () ) { OCCAECAT( PARIATUR[ EUISMOD ] ); };
EXERCITATION <IRURE FUGIAT> ALIQUIP PROIDENT( CONSEQUAT  MAGNA) { OCCAECAT( LUPTATE
(std::get<FUGIAT>( CONSECTETUR { } ) ) ); }; EXERCITATION <ALIQUIP ... MOLLIT> QUIS
EXCEPTEUR(DESERUNT(MOLLIT) ... DUIS) { (PROIDENT<MOLLIT>(DUIS), ...); }
#define LABORUM 062u,035u,05u, 011u, 035u, 05u,0b1000ll, 011u, 060u, 0b0ll, 020u, \
013u, 0b11ll,0b10ll, 021u, 0u,0b0ll, 021u, 0154u, 0b0ll, 035u, 1ll, 0b101ll, 0ll, \
032u, 0b11ll,0b10ll, 046u, 0b1ll, 044u, 0b1011ll, 074u, 046u,057u,074u, 0b1001ll, \
0135u,045U,0B10LL, 061u,057u, 074u,061u, 0165U,0100U,0B110LL, 0B10LL,0113U, 074U, \
061U, 0B0LL, 1ll,074u, 0113U, 0B11LL, 0b0ll, 0113u, 0b1001ll, 0b10ll,075u, 0116u, \
0103u, 0105U, 0B101LL,0b0ll, 0b1ll, 0b10ll,0105u, 0b1001ll, 0124u, 0b1ll,0b101ll, \
0112u, 0114u, 0126u, 0b110ll, 0B10LL,0b1001ll, 0111u, 0136u, 0127u, 0b0ll, 0126u, \
0137U,  0B0LL, 0225U, 0127U, 0165U,  0130U, 0B10LL, 0132U,  0166u, 0157u,  0141u, \
0B101LL, 0B110LL, 0B11LL, 0B0LL, 0b1000ll, 0156u,0146U, 0153u, 1ll, 0b0ll, 0135u, \
0b0ll,0B1000LL, 0156U, 0b0ll,0135U, 0B0LL, 0161u, 0b11ll,0b10ll, 0170U, 0B1000LL, \
0230U, 0225U,0170U,0b11ll, 0b10ll,0174u,0B1000LL, 0B0LL,0176u,0171u,0b0ll, 0201U, \
0B10LL,0207U, 0204u,0233u,0b110ll, 0225u,0232u, 0233u,0b10ll, 0212U,0233U, 0230U, \
0B1LL, 0B110LL, 0227u,0221u, 0b100ll, 0b1000ll,0B0LL,0B1LL,0230u, 0226u,0B1011LL, \
0236U,0156U,0b0ll,0B1000LL,0156u,0230U,0236U,1LL,0230U,0242u,0242u,0B10LL,0B11LL, \
0230U,0233U
#define VENIAM LABORUM
```

Veo algunas macros al iniciar el archivo y después un galimatías que incluye el "*Lorem Ipsum*" ¿Alguien puede ayudarme a entender este código?

Comment: Tratar de descifrar esto sí que es inutilis laborum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El código que muestras está [ofuscado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ofuscaci%C3%B3n) probablemente con motivos humorísticos, ya que es una ofuscación muy mala. No voy a perder el tiempo en explicar qué substitución hace cada una de las macros de las primeras líneas del archivo `lorem_ipsum`, es más fácil pedirle al preprocesador que nos muestre el código con todas las substituciones ya hechas:

```cpp
auto LUPTATE(auto CONSECTETUR)
{
    return typeid(CONSECTETUR).name();
}

char PARIATUR[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing Elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore Magna aliqua zut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum";;

using  CONSECTETUR = std::tuple<signed char, char, long double, double, float, unsigned char, signed int, unsigned, long, unsigned long, signed long long, unsigned long long>; 

template <auto EUISMOD> auto PROIDENT(unsigned)
{
    std::cout << PARIATUR[EUISMOD];
};
template <auto FUGIAT> auto PROIDENT(long  long)
{
    std::cout << LUPTATE (std::get<FUGIAT>(CONSECTETUR{ }));
};

template <auto ... MOLLIT>
void EXCEPTEUR(decltype(MOLLIT) ... DUIS)
{
    (PROIDENT<MOLLIT>(DUIS), ...);
}
int main()
{
    EXCEPTEUR<062u,035u,05u, 011u, 035u, 05u,0b1000ll, 011u, 060u, 0b0ll, 020u, 013u, 0b11ll,0b10ll, 021u, 0u,0b0ll, 021u, 0154u, 0b0ll, 035u, 1ll, 0b101ll, 0ll, 032u, 0b11ll,0b10ll, 046u, 0b1ll, 044u, 0b1011ll, 074u, 046u,057u,074u, 0b1001ll, 0135u,045U,0B10LL, 061u,057u, 074u,061u, 0165U,0100U,0B110LL, 0B10LL,0113U, 074U, 061U, 0B0LL, 1ll,074u, 0113U, 0B11LL, 0b0ll, 0113u, 0b1001ll, 0b10ll,075u, 0116u, 0103u, 0105U, 0B101LL,0b0ll, 0b1ll, 0b10ll,0105u, 0b1001ll, 0124u, 0b1ll,0b101ll, 0112u, 0114u, 0126u, 0b110ll, 0B10LL,0b1001ll, 0111u, 0136u, 0127u, 0b0ll, 0126u, 0137U, 0B0LL, 0225U, 0127U, 0165U, 0130U, 0B10LL, 0132U, 0166u, 0157u, 0141u, 0B101LL, 0B110LL, 0B11LL, 0B0LL, 0b1000ll, 0156u,0146U, 0153u, 1ll, 0b0ll, 0135u, 0b0ll,0B1000LL, 0156U, 0b0ll,0135U, 0B0LL, 0161u, 0b11ll,0b10ll, 0170U, 0B1000LL, 0230U, 0225U,0170U,0b11ll, 0b10ll,0174u,0B1000LL, 0B0LL,0176u,0171u,0b0ll, 0201U, 0B10LL,0207U, 0204u,0233u,0b110ll, 0225u,0232u, 0233u,0b10ll, 0212U,0233U, 0230U, 0B1LL, 0B110LL, 0227u,0221u, 0b100ll, 0b1000ll,0B0LL,0B1LL,0230u, 0226u,0B1011LL, 0236U,0156U,0b0ll,0B1000LL,0156u,0230U,0236U,1LL,0230U,0242u,0242u,0B10LL,0B11LL, 0230U,0233U>(062u,035u,05u, 011u, 035u, 05u,0b1000ll, 011u, 060u, 0b0ll, 020u, 013u, 0b11ll,0b10ll, 021u, 0u,0b0ll, 021u, 0154u, 0b0ll, 035u, 1ll, 0b101ll, 0ll, 032u, 0b11ll,0b10ll, 046u, 0b1ll, 044u, 0b1011ll, 074u, 046u,057u,074u, 0b1001ll, 0135u,045U,0B10LL, 061u,057u, 074u,061u, 0165U,0100U,0B110LL, 0B10LL,0113U, 074U, 061U, 0B0LL, 1ll,074u, 0113U, 0B11LL, 0b0ll, 0113u, 0b1001ll, 0b10ll,075u, 0116u, 0103u, 0105U, 0B101LL,0b0ll, 0b1ll, 0b10ll,0105u, 0b1001ll, 0124u, 0b1ll,0b101ll, 0112u, 0114u, 0126u, 0b110ll, 0B10LL,0b1001ll, 0111u, 0136u, 0127u, 0b0ll, 0126u, 0137U, 0B0LL, 0225U, 0127U, 0165U, 0130U, 0B10LL, 0132U, 0166u, 0157u, 0141u, 0B101LL, 0B110LL, 0B11LL, 0B0LL, 0b1000ll, 0156u,0146U, 0153u, 1ll, 0b0ll, 0135u, 0b0ll,0B1000LL, 0156U, 0b0ll,0135U, 0B0LL, 0161u, 0b11ll,0b10ll, 0170U, 0B1000LL, 0230U, 0225U,0170U,0b11ll, 0b10ll,0174u,0B1000LL, 0B0LL,0176u,0171u,0b0ll, 0201U, 0B10LL,0207U, 0204u,0233u,0b110ll, 0225u,0232u, 0233u,0b10ll, 0212U,0233U, 0230U, 0B1LL, 0B110LL, 0227u,0221u, 0b100ll, 0b1000ll,0B0LL,0B1LL,0230u, 0226u,0B1011LL, 0236U,0156U,0b0ll,0B1000LL,0156u,0230U,0236U,1LL,0230U,0242u,0242u,0B10LL,0B11LL, 0230U,0233U);
}
```

Lo primero que vemos es una función llamada `LUPTATE`, esta función está usando una manera moderna de definir plantillas, el código equivalente con la manera tradicional sería:

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto LUPTATE(T CONSECTETUR)
{
    return typeid(CONSECTETUR).name();
}
```

Lo que hace esta plantilla es devolver el nombre del tipo que recibe como parámetro, este nombre es dependiente de implementación, así que cada compilador podría dar un resultado diferente.

Acto seguido se define un alias para una tupla con los tipos `signed char`, `char`, `long double`, `double`, `float`, `unsigned char`, `signed int`, `unsigned`, `long`, `unsigned long`, `signed long long` y `unsigned long long` dándole el nombre de `CONSECTETUR`.

A continuación tenemos una formación de caracteres llamada `PARIATUR` que contiene el "*Lorem Ipsum*", seguida de dos versiones de una función plantilla con parámetro no-tipo llamada `PROIDENT`.

1. La primera versión de `PROIDENT` recibe un parámetro entero sin signo (`unsigned`) y muestra por consola uno de los caracteres de la formación `PARIATUR`; selecciona el carácter a mostrar mediante su parámetro plantilla no-tipo.

   ```cpp
   template <auto EUISMOD> auto PROIDENT(unsigned)
   {
    std::cout << PARIATUR[EUISMOD];
   };
   ```
2. La segunda versión de `PROIDENT` recibe un parámetro entero largo (`long long`) y muestra por consola el resultado de llamar la función que muestra el nombre de un tipo (`LUPTATE`) usando uno de los tipos de la tupla `CONSECTETUR`, se usa el parámetro no-tipo de la plantilla para seleccionar el elemento de la tupla.

   ```cpp
   template <auto FUGIAT> auto PROIDENT(long  long)
   {
    std::cout << LUPTATE (std::get<FUGIAT>(CONSECTETUR{ }));
   };
   ```

Y para acabar, tenemos la función `EXCEPTEUR` que hace todo el trabajo. Se trata de una función plantilla variádica que recibe como parámetros no-tipo una colección de valores, pasa cada uno de estos valores a la función `PROIDENT` como parámetro no-tipo y desambigua entre ambas versiones de la función pasando el mismo valor como parámetro tradicional.

Podemos ver que en la llamada a `EXCEPTEUR` en `main` se le pasan dos tipos de valores:

- Valores acabados en `u`, que son literales de entero sin signo (`unsigned`).
- Valores acabados en `ll`, que son literales de entero largo (`long long`).

Lo que me parece ver es que está usando el "*Lorem Ipsum*" como un [Cifrado Vignère](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cifrado_de_Vigen%C3%A8re), en que los valores pasados a `EXCEPTEUR` se usan de índice sobre las letras de `PARIATUR` o el retorno de `LUPTATE`. Vamos a verlo con un par de ejemplos:

- El literal `035u` es el número 35<sub>8</sub> (los literales que empiezan con un cero, están en notación octal) que equivale a 29<sub>10</sub>, al tener el sufijo `u` es un entero sin signo; esto significa que llamaremos a `PROIDENT(unsigned)` con el valor `29`, el vigesimonoveno carácter de `PARIATUR` es: **`n`**.
- El literal `0b1000ll` es el número 1000<sub>2</sub> (los literales que empiezan con `0b`, están en notación binaria) que equivale a 8<sub>10</sub>, al tener sufijo `ll` es un entero largo; esto significa que llamaremos a `PROIDENT(long long)` con el valor `8`, el octavo tipo de la tupla `CONSECTETUR` es `signed int` cuyo nombre dependerá del compilador, en GCC parece ser `l`.